# How to remove CodeMix virus

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally installed CodeMix malware when installing Anguar IDE plugin to my Eclipse4.6. Now everytime I open a JS file it shows CodeMix registration window and I am unable to open JS files if I don't provide my email account. I tried 3 times of unstalling CodeMix and then restarting Eclipse, but failed 3 times. Every time Eclipse says successfully uninstalled. However The virus/malware CodeMix is still there asking for my email account. It is a Windows10.

Question 1: How can I completely remove CodeMix?

Question 2: Is it a crime to develop something like CodeMix in US?

Comment: CodeMix is not blocking uninstallation, and definitely not a crime. You are hitting an unfortunate side effect of how Eclipse plug-in installation works when installing a marketplace entry that has more than one feature chosen during install.

Comment: This showed up in my editor today without me installing anything. All of a sudden, all my git diff changes were in my editor and I couldn't turn it off. I rebooted Eclipse and got the welcome screen for codemix. I did not install it or anything else on my box in months. However I did connect to public WiFi and I think this is where it came from. Following these instructions I was able to get rid of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to uninstall software installed from the **Eclipse Marketplace** is by using the Marketplace client itself. Simply go to **Help > Eclipse Marketplace...** entry, and then the **Installed** tab where you can click **Uninstall**.

Uninstalling software in Eclipse can be difficult if you try to do it from the Help > Installation Details approach as you either need to roll back all changes you've made by using a **Revert** to a previous point of the installation or find all plugins that you installed from the marketplace.  If you miss some plugins when doing the manual approach, Eclipse won't fully remove it.

In this case, CodeMix is not actually "reinstalling" itself as your question reads like.  It was just never removed by Eclipse itself.

Comment: This didnt work for me. There was a codemix menu in help with uninstall option. I uninstall it and now I am unable to uninstall. It still lie there. I tried every thing but of no use.

Answer (score 6):

The installation of mistakenly installed plug-ins can be undone as follows:

1. In ***Help > About Eclipse IDE*** hit the ***Installation Details*** button
2. In the *Installation Details* dialog, in the tab ***Installation History* select the installation point** before the mistaken installation and hit the ***Revert*** button

Please note that this does not delete files created by the plug-in itself. As far as I know, this plug-in creates a **subdirectory in the user's home directory** occupying a lot of disk space.

To the second question: As far as I know, not the development but the distribution can be illegal in the US, for example when spying without the user's consent or when licenses (including open source licenses) are violated.

Answer (score 3):

There are about 6~7 CodeMix plugins including Angular, CodeMix Essentials and 3 more. I had to search by 'mix' and then remove everything in the search results. It is gone now.

Comment: This is the right answer. To fully remove software in Eclipse, you have to remove the "root" feature or features that you installed. Next time, you'll find it easier if you do the uninstall using the Eclipse Marketplace UI as from there it will install everything you chose (or was selected by default).

Answer (score 1):

As a work around I just went and removed everything it was trying to be the preferred editor for (CodeMix/Editors/Preferred Editors).  It seems to have made it less of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to you, but in my installation Groovy Development Tools was interfering with adding and removing plugins.  After removing that, I have been able to add and remove other things without difficulty.
I am using Eclipse 2020-12.

Answer (score 0):

I installed CodeMix when I was looking for an editor for Go files. They definitely have an aggressive model when it comes to trying to monetize Eclipse plugins. I think it is a shame that they went so overboard on the marketing, because the product itself shows a lot of work, and I would have been willing to pay for something less intrusive.

That said,  they now have a pretty good uninstaller built into the product. Just go to (in the Eclipse menu) Help > CodeMix > Uninstall CodeMix. This seems to have cleared it all out for me.